# Center the logos on the page and get them in this 3x2 grid?

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to center them  and keep them centered according to the window size.

This is how its supposed to look like (made in xd)

[image]

(the borders are just for my orientation)

Code:

```css
#logos {
  outline: 5px dashed green;
}

.griditem {
  outline: 5px dashed red;
}

img {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>HFFoto - Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="applicationStylesheet" href="portfolio_kunden.css" />
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="fullbodybg">
    <div id="logos">
      <img class="griditem" id="hygge_logo" src="Hygge_Logo_final.png" srcset="Hygge_Logo_final.png, Hygge_Logo_final.png">
      <img class="griditem" id="wellyou_Logo_Rot_Schwarz400" src="wellyou_Logo_Rot_Schwarz400.png" srcset="wellyou_Logo_Rot_Schwarz400.png 1x, wellyou_Logo_Rot_Schwarz400@2x.png 2x">
      <img class="griditem" id="Logo_muhlenbach" src="Logo_wei_.png" srcset="Logo_wei_.png 1x, Logo_wei_@2x.png 2x">
      <img class="griditem" id="Logo_neu_DOMKRUG" src="Logo_neu_DOMKRUG.png" srcset="Logo_neu_DOMKRUG.png 1x, Logo_neu_DOMKRUG@2x.png 2x">
      <img class="griditem" id="OMK_Kopie" src="OMK_Kopie.png" srcset="OMK_Kopie.png 1x, OMK_Kopie@2x.png 2x">
      <img class="griditem" id="hygge_logo_platzhalter" src="Hygge_Logo_final.png" srcset="Hygge_Logo_final.png, Hygge_Logo_final.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please use placeholder.com for images instead of local images not available to StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is flexbox. Add one more container to your code:

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="logos">
      <img class="griditem" id="hygge_logo" src="Hygge_Logo_final.png" srcset="Hygge_Logo_final.png, Hygge_Logo_final.png">
      <img class="griditem" id="wellyou_Logo_Rot_Schwarz400" src="wellyou_Logo_Rot_Schwarz400.png" srcset="wellyou_Logo_Rot_Schwarz400.png 1x, wellyou_Logo_Rot_Schwarz400@2x.png 2x">
      <img class="griditem" id="Logo_muhlenbach" src="Logo_wei_.png" srcset="Logo_wei_.png 1x, Logo_wei_@2x.png 2x">
      <img class="griditem" id="Logo_neu_DOMKRUG" src="Logo_neu_DOMKRUG.png" srcset="Logo_neu_DOMKRUG.png 1x, Logo_neu_DOMKRUG@2x.png 2x">
      <img class="griditem" id="OMK_Kopie" src="OMK_Kopie.png" srcset="OMK_Kopie.png 1x, OMK_Kopie@2x.png 2x">
      <img class="griditem" id="hygge_logo_platzhalter" src="Hygge_Logo_final.png" srcset="Hygge_Logo_final.png, Hygge_Logo_final.png">
    </div>
  </div>
```

And in your stylesheet:

```
#container
{
   width: /* Your width */
   height: /* Your height */
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center; /* This will center container with items horizontally */
   align-items: center; /* This will center container with items vertically */
}

#logos {
  outline: 5px dashed green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-items: space-evenly;
}

.griditem {
  outline: 5px dashed red;
  width: 30%; /* Three items in one line */
  height: /* Your height */
}

img {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. so this almost works but the 3 in a row only works when the browser window is at almost half the width, at full size there are still all logos in a row. can i limit the logo container so it always only shows 3 ?

Comment: Try add width: 100% to #logos. Check my example here, it may help: https://codepen.io/Sa1m0n/pen/YzybzNp

Answer (score 2):

You can use css flex and grid

Example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HFFoto - Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="applicationStylesheet" href="portfolio_kunden.css"/>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
    .logos {
        outline: 5px dashed green;
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; // sets 3 columns
        grid-gap: 2rem // sets the spacing between elements
    }

    .griditem {
        outline: 5px dashed red;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 300px;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fullbodybg">
    <div class="logos">
        <div class="grid">
            <img class="griditem" id="hygge_logo" src="Hygge_Logo_final.png" srcset="Hygge_Logo_final.png, Hygge_Logo_final.png" >
            <img class="griditem" id="wellyou_Logo_Rot_Schwarz400" src="wellyou_Logo_Rot_Schwarz400.png" srcset="wellyou_Logo_Rot_Schwarz400.png 1x, wellyou_Logo_Rot_Schwarz400@2x.png 2x">
            <img class="griditem" id="Logo_muhlenbach" src="Logo_wei_.png" srcset="Logo_wei_.png 1x, Logo_wei_@2x.png 2x">
            <img class="griditem" id="Logo_neu_DOMKRUG" src="Logo_neu_DOMKRUG.png" srcset="Logo_neu_DOMKRUG.png 1x, Logo_neu_DOMKRUG@2x.png 2x">
            <img class="griditem" id="OMK_Kopie" src="OMK_Kopie.png" srcset="OMK_Kopie.png 1x, OMK_Kopie@2x.png 2x">
            <img class="griditem" id="hygge_logo_platzhalter" src="Hygge_Logo_final.png" srcset="Hygge_Logo_final.png, Hygge_Logo_final.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also changed id logos to class.